# change JSON structure using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, oop

This is my code..

```
var result = data.map(function(item){
    return {
        category:item.category,
        key:item.key,
        value:item.value
    }
});
console.log(result);
```

This is what is getting printed out in console..

```
Array[4]
0: Object
category: "common"
key: "Food"
value: "food"

1: Object
category: "welcome"
key: "title"
value: "Welcome..."

2: Object
category: "welcome"
key: "app_description"
value: "In this App "

3: Object
category: "welcome"
key: "select_location"
value: "Select Location"
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve

```
{
    common:{
        "Food" : "food"
    },
    welcome:{
        title : Welcome...,
        app_description : "In this App",
        select_location : "Select Location"

    }
}
```

This is the code I'm trying .but it is not working..

```
return {
    item.category:{
        item.key:item.value;                    
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this? I dont want to use GSON or any other third-party JS..How can i get this done using only core JS?

Comment: can you supply the value of `data` before you start manipulating it? as referenced in your `.map()` function?

Comment: are you sure, you want to use map() for this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, what you want as a result is an object, not an array. So you can't use `.map()` which only maps one array to another array.

You want **[`.reduce()`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/reduce)**.

```
var result = data.reduce(function (result, item) {
    // Create the object the first time it arrives
    result[item.category] = result[item.category] || {};
    // Add the field
    result[item.category][item.key]=item.value;
    // Return the resulting object
    return result;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

`.reduce()`'s reduction function takes two (with 2 more optional) parameters. The **cumulative result**, and the **current item**. The returned value is the result after the current item has been processed on it.

The second parameter for `.reduce()` (the first being the reduction function), is the **initial value**, this value will get passed as `result` for the first iteration.

Comment: you assign wrong object, seems it would be like `result[item.category][item.key]=item.value` and also `result[item.category] = {}` if it not exist

Comment: @Grundy You are correct. I fixed and added comments.

Comment: Thank you Madara Uchiha.. :)

Answer (score 2):

**[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)** comes to rescue.

```
var result = data.reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue) {
    previousValue[currentValue.category] = previousValue[currentValue.category] || {};
    previousValue[currentValue.category][currentValue.key] = currentValue.value;
    return previousValue;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also try:

```
var data = [
    {
        category: "common",
        key: "Food",
        value: "food"
    },
    {
        category: "welcome",
        key: "title",
        value: "Welcome..."
    },
    {
        category: "welcome",
        key: "app_description",
        value: "In this App "
    },
    {
        category: "welcome",
        key: "select_location",
        value: "Select Location"
    }
];
var obj = {};
for (var i in data) {
    if(!obj[data[i].category]){
        obj[data[i].category] = {};
    }
    obj[data[i].category][data[i].key] = data[i].value;
}
console.log(obj);
```